# Is it possible to wrap a Doxygen filter command in quotes?

Tags: cmd, doxygen, popen

I am trying to write a Doxygen file filter that lives in a subdirectory that works from Doxyfile on both Windows and Linux.

```
Doxyfile
/scripts
    myfilter
```

I seem to be unable to specify the path using a forward-slash on Windows unless it is quoted:

```
"scripts/myfilter"
```

However, trying to quote the command in Doxyfile does not work.

```
FILTER_PATTERNS        = *.glsl=""scripts/runpython" scripts/doxygen-glslfilter.py"
```

On Windows, you get an error that implies the quotes don't exist.

> 'scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Doxygen uses popen() to run these commands and will remove the wrapping quotes around the command, but it does not seem to remove all quotes.

popen() call:

https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/src/definition.cpp#L745

filter name quote strip:

https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/src/util.cpp#L2458

However, the result is the same as if there were no quotes.

**Update**

I was able to get command logging in Doxygen, and it appears the extra quotes are being stripped in an odd way.  You can see how there is a space in front of the command.

```
Executing popen(` scripts/runpython scripts/doxygen-glslfilter.py "C:/dev/g3d/G3D10/data-files/shader/AlphaFilter.glsl"`)
```

**Update**

I submitted a bug report/feature request but I doubt it will be read.

[Doxygen Bug Report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=792846)

Comment: You're using double quotes within double quotes, thus cancelling out each other. Try `'"scripts/runpython" scripts/doxygen-glslfilter.py'`

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750869/what-is-the-qhg-location-path-relative-to-for-doxygen.

For this pull request 703 has been submitted( https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/703).

Comment: pull request 703 has been integrated in the master branch on github.

Comment: I've added a comment https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6320#issuecomment-486666030. I am unable to make this work using Windows 7 and Doxygen 1.8.15? Any workaround available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was reported to the doxygen project, and they have provided a solution where any '/' in the command is replaced by '\' on Windows.

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=792846

This was done to resolve a similar issue here:
[What is the QHG_LOCATION path relative to for doxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750869/what-is-the-qhg-location-path-relative-to-for-doxygen)

The pull request for the project on github here: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/703

Answer (score 0):

When using double quotes within double quotes in a single string, it sees the first double quote as the start string and the next double quote as the end of the string.
So in your example:

```
""scripts/runpython" scripts/doxygen-glslfilter.py"
```

The first 2 quotes are seen as open and close, then it sees `scripts/runpython` as the next command etc.

I do not have the same tool,  but these 2 examples will probably sort out your issue.

This example wraps each set in double quotes, and the entire set in single quotes.

```
FILTER_PATTERNS = *.glsl='"scripts/runpython" "scripts/doxygen-glslfilter.py"'
```

Where this example wraps the first set in double quotes and the entire set in single quotes.

```
FILTER_PATTERNS = *.glsl='"scripts/runpython" scripts/doxygen-glslfilter.py'
```

*NOTE!!* I am unable to test this as I do not have the same environment as you. I am therefore not sure if the second option will work, as it might also need `scripts/doxygen-glslfilter.py` in double quotes, I am adding it to the answer regardless.

Comment: Unfortunately, the single quote breaks the Doxygen parser.  It doesn't grab the entire command.

It should be unquoting the full command, but seems to be doing more.

Comment: and have you tried this `"scripts/runpython scripts/doxygen-glslfilter.py"` or `"scripts/runpython" "scripts/doxygen-glslfilter.py"`

Comment: The naked "scripts/runpython ..." results in the error in the original post as cmd seems to not parse past the / unless quoted.

Comment: can you please swop the / for \

Comment: like this: `scripts\runpython scripts\doxygen-glslfilter.py`

Comment: That breaks the goal of working on Linux and Windows.

Comment: ok, was not aware you're working on Linux, because of the Batch tag.

Comment: what was the last command you ran that gave the results in the Update of your question?

Comment: You're right!  That was the first line I wrote in the post, and it's not there.  That's completely unintentional to mislead you.

Comment: The same as the original in the post with ""scripts/runpython" ..."  It looks odd to me too, but it demonstrates what I want.

Comment: please try this as well. Sorry for this but I cannot test the environment myself. `""./scripts/runpython" "./scripts/doxygen-glslfilter.py""` with quotes being in the same place as it was when you ran it.

Comment: This works when I test it directly on the command line, but when using it in the Doxyfile, it ends up with the quotes removed somehow and then errors.

I think the issue is in Doxygen at this point or at least the limitation.

Comment: I will try and get the environment replicated and see what I can figure out.

Comment: I might have to just post it as a bug to Doxygen and see what happens.  I appreciate the ideas!