# What is the QHG_LOCATION path relative to for doxygen?

Tags: qt, doxygen

When I set `QHG_LOCATION` to be an absolute path, I can create a valid doxygen documentation in html and qch. If I put qhelpgenerator and its DLLs into the current directory `./` and set `QHG_LOCATION=qhelpgenerator`, it also works. But I cannot figure out how to put the qhelpgenerator into a subdirectory `qt/bin/qhelpgenerator` and have doxygen find it. It always says

```
error: failed to run qhelpgenerator on index.qhp
```

which means that it could not find qhelpgenerator.

So the question is: If I want `QHG_LOCATION` to be a relative path, what directory is it relative to? It is neither relative to `./` nor to the html output directory.

Comment: Try to run with ```-d extcmd```, so ```doxygen -d extcmd```, to see which external commands are executed. This might give a hint. Also try to execute the given command 'by hand' outside of doxygen.

Comment: I just saw in the code ```QDir::setCurrent(Config_getString(HTML_OUTPUT));``` just befors starting the ghelpgenerator, so path should be relative to the ```HTML_OUTPUT``` directory (or in the path).

Comment: Thank you, I just figured it out. If you want to convert your comment into an answer, I will mark yours as the solution :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging the problem can be done by outputting the external commands executed:
`doxygen -d extcmd` and execute the given command 'by hand' outside of doxygen.

From the documentation of `QHG_LOCATION`:

> The QHG_LOCATION tag can be used to specify the location of Qt's qhelpgenerator. If nonempty
>   doxygen will try to run qhelpgenerator on the generated .qhp file.

and from the documenattion of `QCH_FILE`:

> If the QHG_LOCATION tag is specified, the QCH_FILE tag can be used to specify the file name of
>   the resulting .qch file. The path specified is relative to the HTML output folder.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, both `QHG_LOCATION` and `QCH_FILE` must be relative to the HTML output directory. Furthermore, you must use backslashes `\` as directory separators on Windows. Forward slashes are supported in the rest of the doxyfile but not here.

I find both issues quite irritating, but this is the way it is.

Thanks to albert for a helpful comment!

Comment: Regarding the backslash problem.: Does this occur in ```QCH_FILE``` and ```QHG_LOCATION``` or just one of them? and which version of the qhelpgenerator are you using (as nowadays a lot of programs accept forward and backward slashes on Windows).

Comment: Backslashes are only required for `QHG_LOCATION`. I use qhelpgenerator 1.0 from Qt 4.8.7. I assume that doxygen does a plain system call and that's why it fails on Windows if using forward slashes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about a solution for this (it is on the not so small list).

Comment: I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 703, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/703).  This is regarding the path, for the HTML directory 'annoyance' there is no real solution (due to compatibility).